# How to shorten xpath for multilingual support having same attribute with multiple values but using contains function?

Tags: xpath, text, attributes, multilingual, xpath-2.0

Earlier my xpath for a certain image element was written with text containing English words.

Now, with vernacular support it has lengthened.
Seeking help to shorten it.

XPath with English support:

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Web') and contains(@text,'Result')]/preceding-sibling::android.widget.ImageView[@index=0];
```

XPath supporting Tamil as well:

```
//android.widget.TextView[(contains(@text,'வெப்') or contains(@text,'Web')) and (contains(@text,'விளைவாக') or  contains(@text,'Result') )]/preceding-sibling::android.widget.ImageView[@index=0];
```

Is there any way I can shorten the above Xpath ? Something like below (but not exactly using pipe):

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Web'|'வெப்') and contains(@text,'Result'|'விளைவாக')]/preceding-sibling::android.widget.ImageView[@index=0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the XPath 2.0 `matches` function e.g. `matches(@text,'வெப்|Web')`.